# Find all models of given theory

Tags: logic

$\def\imp{\Rightarrow}$I have a theory $T=\{p \imp \neg q, \neg q, r \imp q, r \imp \neg p\}$ over $P=\{p, q, r\}$

I need to find all models of theory $T$.

My question is whether I could use any systematic approach? Instead of just "inventing" how particular models look.

My idea was to use the method of analytic tableaux. Where $$T((p \imp \neg q) \land \neg q \land (r \imp q) \land (r \imp \neg p))$$ would be a root.

Then every branch without a conflict would give me one particular model.

Comment: Click edit to see how I got the nicer symbol "$\imp$" which has the appropriate length and spacing. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the following approach is hardly systematic, here's how I found all models very quickly and easily:

Given $T=\{p \to \neg q, \neg q, r \to q, r \to \neg p\}$, observe that we already have one atom, $\neg q$.

Because $r \to q \equiv \neg q \to \neg r$, it follows that $\neg r$. So every model $M$ of $T$ must have $q^M=r^M=\bot$ ($false$).

The two formulas involving $p$ are $p\to\neg q$ and $r\to\neg p\equiv p\to\neg r$. In any model $M$ of $T$, $(\neg q)^M = (\neg r)^M = \top$, so the value these formulas will be $(p^M \Rightarrow \top)$, which is $\top$ no matter what the value of $p$.

Thus,

- $(p=\top, q=\bot, r=\bot)$ is a model of $T$,
- $(p=\bot, q=\bot, r=\bot)$ is a model of $T$,

and there are no other possibilities.

Larger or more challenging theories can't be 'eyeballed' this easily, and for them, analytic tableaux provide the proper tool.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the tableaux method will give you all possible models, because you must remember that each step in the method simply corresponds to splitting into all the possible cases. So obviously once you have identified which are the open branches, you have indeed found all possible models.

On the other hand, for small number of propositional variables (at most 4), it may be faster to simply list all possible combinations and see which ones satisfy the set of formulae you have.